# Processing each line of a textarea form in a script

Tags: php

I've learned it's possible to trim a string from a textarea and put break tags after it, so each sentence written at a new line in the textbox will also be written at a new line in the PHP file.

This is the snippet:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$text = trim($_POST['textarea']);
$text = nl2br($text);
echo $text;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The thing is that my true intentions are:

1. Use the contents of each line in the textbox for a certain script
2. Print the contents of each line with the results from the script added all separated by lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
    $text = trim($_POST['textarea']);
    $text = explode ("\n", $text);

    foreach ($text as $line) {
       echo myFunction($line);
       echo "< hr />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: For end of line possibly better could be PHP_EOL, to make it platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function **explode** lets you take a string and blow it up into smaller pieces. Store this array for use in other scripts

```
$str_arr = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']);
//$str_arr can be used for other script
```