# Send multiple values thru one textarea in a form

Tags: php, forms, textarea

I'm trying to find out if its possible to send several different form values thru one textarea.
So instead of have one text input field for first name, one for last name, one for street address etc. I want to be able to add all info in one text area and seperate each value with a line break.

Each value need to be inserted in different columns in the assign table in the database.

It should be done i php.

Any pointers or tips of how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Fredrik

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Processing each line of a textarea form in a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211623/php-processing-each-line-of-a-textarea-form-in-a-script)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work with

```
$array = explode("\n", $text);
```

so you have all values in an array.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it will not always just be \n e.g. windows uses \r\n. Thats why it is better to use \R, which matches all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible - though I would question the user experience of doing it this way and the amount of extra work you are giving yourself. Remember that users are generally not used to having one big textbox for everything - and you will need to trust that they do actually put the line break in, which I guarantee they won't.

In any event, you could take the content and then split it on \n using preg_split with a regular expression. I think the following regular expression would work

```
$lines = preg_split("/(\R+)/", $textbox_content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I totaly agree that users wont be able to handle this whitout causing alot of additional work for me. But I will be using this myself to add this info into the database.